# Firebase Realtime Database: Split method in security rules: Error saving rules - Line 6: No such method/property 'split'

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am storing user messages in real time database like this:
`<USER_1_UID>__<USER_2_UID>`
now before creating the object, I am sorting it so to ensure that for two users the key always matches.

I want a user to be able to read/write the messages only if the key when split through `__` contains the uid of the user that requested it.

For example:

`uid1__uid2` chat must only be accessible to `uid1` and `uid2` and no one else.

One method could be: `$uidCombo.contains(auth.uid)` but this will fail for the use case:
`uid11_uid2` where both `uid11` and `uid1` would be able to access the messages.

My major question is does split method exist in firebase as I see it in suggestions:
[image]

```
"messages": {
        "$uidcombo": {
          ".read":"$uidcombo.split('__').contains(auth.uid)",
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the reference documentation for the [String type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#string_methods) in security rules, it does not support a `split` method. So it seems like a bug in the auto-completer that the rules editor uses that it shows that.

To achieve your goal, you could use `beginsWith` and `endsWith` to test for the UID.

```
".read":"$uidcombo.beginsWith(auth.uid+'__') || 
         $uidcombo.endsWith('__'+auth.uid)"
```